# Using select to determine a stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am calling a stored procedure where I'm trying to cast a number into a datetime (as I'm grabbing it from excel so it converts dates to numbers:

```
exec UpdateInvoices @InvoiceDate = select cast(cast(42109 as datetime) as date)
```

This doesn't work, I get incorrect syntax near Select.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: any specific reason you don't want to set `@InvoiceDate` separately and then pass it to SP as normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your parameter first.

```
DECLARE @DateParam date 

SELECT  @DateParam = cast(cast(42109 as datetime) as date)
EXEC UpdateInvoices @InvoiceDate = @DateParam
```

Comment: Trying to do it in one line as I have an autofill in excel which populates it

Comment: @Evonet Not sure if it can be done in one line. Other alternative is to modify your stored proc to receive `varchar` and cast value inside the proc.

Comment: @Evonet your excel column is populated with the query you have provided? Can you change that logic to generate an `sp_executesql` statement instead of `exec` proc statement? Will that be acceptable? if yes, you can then put query I provided as parameter to `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 1):

Just lose the `select`:

```
exec UpdateInvoices @InvoiceDate = cast(cast(42109 as datetime) as date)
```